# configure apache web server in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port

is there any way by which i can change the port number and localhost name on which apache web server runs in ubuntu ?

Comment: Please set some useful tags. "help" isn't very detailed nor helpful in categorizing your question...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check out `Listen` parameter in httpd.conf configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file:

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

or the files in:

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Answer (score 0):

go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

```
<VirtualHost *:[whateverport]>
     ...
     ServerAlias [whatever]
     ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and add the listen to in the 
/etc/apache2/ports.conf